# How do I update the CellTemplate DataTemplate control when the CellEditingTemplate DataTemplate control changes its bound value?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a Template Column in my DataGrid that looks like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox
                DisplayMemberPath="Item"
                Header="Item"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Data.AssetDescriptions, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding AssetDescriptionID}"
                SelectedValuePath="AssetDescriptionID" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The ViewModel has a public property containing the Asset Descriptions:

```
public IEnumerable<AssetDescription> AssetDescriptions { get; set; }
```

Where `AssetDescription` is essentially:

```
public class AssetDescription
{
    public int AssetDescriptionID { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; } // Description
}
```

The DataGrid itself is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Asset> Assets` property, where `Asset` contains both `AssetDescriptionID` and `Item` (description).  To accomplish that, I join the Assets  table to the AssetDescriptions table, like so:

```
var assets = _conn.Query<Asset>(
                @"SELECT A.AssetDescriptionID, D.Item 
                    FROM Assets A
                    JOIN AssetDescriptions D
                      ON D.AssetDescriptionID = A.AssetDescriptionID");

Assets = new ObservableCollection<Asset>(assets);
```

This all works perfectly, *except* that the `TextBlock` in the `CellTemplate` `DataTemplate` does not get updated to the new description when a new value is selected in the `ComboBox`.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only bind to the `AssetDescriptionID`-Property of your `Asset`.
`Item` will never be touched (which your `CellTemplate` binds to).

**Option 1:**
Try using a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` instead of `DataGridTemplateColumn`
`Item` (on `Asset`) is then no longer needed

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn 
    DisplayMemberPath="Item"
    Header="Item"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data.AssetDescriptions, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding AssetDescriptionID}"
    SelectedValuePath="AssetDescriptionID">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

**Option 2:** If you really need the `Item`/description on your `Asset`
Easiest solution will be to bind the whole object(`AssetDescription`).

Change your `Asset` to this

```
class Asset
{
    ...
    public AssetDescription AssetDescription {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

And your `CellEditingTemplate` to this

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox
        DisplayMemberPath="Item"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Data.AssetDescriptions, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding AssetDescription }" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And `CellTemplate` to this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AssetDescription.Item}" />
```

**Edit**: 
You can also use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` for Option 2

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn 
    DisplayMemberPath="Item"
    Header="Item"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data.AssetDescriptions, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding AssetDescription}">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: I like option two.